# How to make scrolling collapsing navigation navbar-fixed-top?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

How to make scrolling collapsing navigation `navbar-fixed-top` `bootstrap4`?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.2.0/js/tether.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container-fluid">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-light bg-faded">
   <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Fixed top</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#exCollapsingNavbar" aria-controls="exCollapsingNavbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
       &#9776;
     </button>
     <div class="collapse" id="exCollapsingNavbar">
       <div class="p-a-1">
         <ul class="nav navbar-nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
       <li class="nav-item">
         <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Active</a>
       </li>
       <li class="nav-item">
         <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
       </li>
       <li class="nav-item">
         <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
       </li>
       <li class="nav-item">
         <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
       </li>
       <li class="nav-item">
         <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
       </li>
       <li class="nav-item">
         <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
       </li>
       <li class="nav-item">
         <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
       </li>
       <li class="nav-item">
         <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
       </li>
       <li class="nav-item">
         <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
       </li>
       <li class="nav-item">
         <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
       </li>
       <li class="nav-item">
         <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
       </li>
       <li class="nav-item">
         <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
       </li>
       <li class="nav-item">
         <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
       </li>
       <li class="nav-item">
         <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
       </li>
       <li class="nav-item">
         <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
       </li>
       <li class="nav-item">
         <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
       </li>
       <li class="nav-item">
         <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
       </li>
       <li class="nav-item">
         <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
       </li>
     </ul>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
  </nav>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you show what do you expect? I don't quite get your question.

Comment: @EdvinTenovimas, want as here (you need to reduce the browser window) - http://output.jsbin.com/dovil/, but only the content of the collapse should not be displayed in the navbar.

Comment: If you don't want the content to be displayed in the navbar, where should it go?

Comment: @EdvinTenovimas `<div class="collapse" id="exCollapsingNavbar">..content...</div>`

Comment: But that content is technically in navbar (there is a parent `nav` above this content).

Comment: So, how would you like to get? Inside that `nav` tag or not? I'm not sure what to post right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In 4 alpha you to add some CSS to make the navbar stack vertically when collapse like 3.x..

```
.navbar .navbar-nav>.nav-item {
    float: none;
    margin-left: .1rem;
}
.navbar .navbar-nav {
    float:none !important;
    max-height: 240px;
    overflow: auto;
}
.navbar .collapse.in, .navbar .collapsing  {
    clear:both;
}
```

**Demo:** http://www.codeply.com/go/zeSsTQr8S9